# Mixed effect model not returning all coefficients

Tags: r, mixed-models, coefficients

I am running some mixed effect models in R. The code is:

```
m <- lmer(DV ~ FE^2 + FE + (FE^2 | ME) + (FE | ME), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

When getting the coefficients with :

```
coefs <- data.frame(coef(m)[1])
```

I get a dataframe with the coefficients. However, when counting the number of groups it is missing a few. Why might this be? The model failed but my assumption is that it should still always produce a coefficient table showing the coefficients for each level of the Mixed effect.

Comment: Check if some groups were dropped because of missing values or because their coefficients could not be estimated.

Comment: Can you show any warning or error messages you're getting?  Does your data contain NA values?  Note that you need `I(FE^2)` if you want to include a squared term in a model (it's better to use `poly(FE,2)`, though).

Comment: @user2974951 How would I go about checking that?